# Jquery validation of datetimepicker - end date must be greater than start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I currently have a sign up form which requires 2 dates for education, a start date and and end date.  My validation works well for all input fields except these dates.  I need them to check that the start date is before the end date.

I am currently using datetimepicker from the library at http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I have seen examples online using the usual jquery library, but not this particular one and I'm a bit stumped as to how to do the validation.

INITIALISES DATETIMEPICKER

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker_start_time').datetimepicker({
  startDate:'+1971/05/01'//or 1986/12/08
});
```

JQUERY VALIDATION

```
<script>

  $(function() {

    $("#book-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            start_education_date: "required",
            end_education_date: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            agree: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
     });

  });

  </script>
```

Comment: Looks like you could create lessThan and greaterThan methods then group them accordingly with the date rule. cf. http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Set up your sample form on something like jsbin.com with all your dependencies included if you want help with that.